# Is there a down-side to turning on 'Always on' for Azure web sites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

What would be reasons *not* to turn on 'Always on' for a web site hosted on Azure?

Comment: NewRelic profiler does not work with "Always On" turned on.

Answer (score 5):

Always On is a good option to turn on when you have a small number of sites running on your web hosting plan (i.e., your VM).

Disabling Always On lets you host a much larger number of sites on your web hosting plan

With Always On turned off you can host a very large number of sites (in the tens or hundreds) on one Standard or Basic web hosting plan.  That way sites that are not receiving request are torn down, freeing up resources for other sites to use.  If you have 100+ websites all with Always On enabled then they'll use up all the Memory of the machine you're running on even if they're not actually processing customer requests.